# Visual studio 2019 fails to download android SDKs

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sdk-tools

When I am downloading Visual Studio 2019 it shows me this:

[image]

Visual Studio opens and works, but when i am working on xamarin and try to install these components using the Android SDK Manager it fails to download them.
I searched the whole internet for solutions but none of them worked, I even tried to disable TLS 1.3 but that did not work either.
if you have any insights about this problem please inform me
thank you in advance

Comment: what do the logs say the problem is?

Comment: it says "cannot find central directory"

Answer (score 1):

for the future if some one encountered the same problem. after a lot of experiments i found out that it will work properly if you use VPN

The reason i think is that there are some Reagons that are banned from useing google and microsoft services, so VPN will get you through that